# I add an entry to a many to many relationship but when I get an object the list is empty

Tags: java, hibernate, many-to-many

I have these two domains:
Category

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CATEGORY")
public class Category extends Domain {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2592988320455126109L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "CATEGORY_CODE", length = 20, nullable = false)
    @Size(min = 1, max = 20, message = "The category code size is not within limits (0-20)")
    @NotNull(message = "The category code cannot be null")
    private String code;

    @Column(name = "CATEGORY_DESCRIPTION", length = 200, nullable = false)
    @Size(min = 1, max = 200, message = "The category description is not within limits (0-200)")
    @NotNull(message = "The category description cannot be null")
    private String description;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "SOLUTION_CATEGORY_MAPPING",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                    name = "CATEGORY_CODE",
                    referencedColumnName = "CATEGORY_CODE",
                    foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_SOLUTION_CATEGORY_CATEGORY_CODE")),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                    name = "SOLUTION_CODE",
                    referencedColumnName = "SOLUTION_CODE",
                    foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_SOLUTION_CATEGORY_SOLUTION_CODE")))
    private List<Solution> solutions;
```

and Solution

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SOLUTION")
public class Solution extends Domain {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8222656642529326612L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "SOLUTION_CODE", length = 20, nullable = false)
    @Size(min = 1, max = 20, message = "The solution code size is not within limits (0-20)")
    @NotNull(message = "The solution code cannot be null")
    private String code;

    @Column(name = "SOLUTION_DESCRIPTION", length = 200, nullable = false)
    @Size(min = 1, max = 200, message = "The solution description is not within limits (0-200)")
    @NotNull(message = "The solution description cannot be null")
    private String description;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "solutions")
    private List<Category> categories;
```

Based on the annotations another table will be created in the database called SOUTION_CATEGORY_MAPPING which basically maps the solutions to the categories. The fetch is lazy.

In a page I submit the primary keys for one object each and attempt to create an entry in the mapping table.

After having fetched the objects/entries corresponding to the primary keys I call this method:

```
private void insertRelationship(CategoryKey categoryKey, SolutionKey solutionKey) {
        Solution solutionToBeEdited = solutionAccess.fetchByPrimaryKey(solutionKey);
        Category categoryToBeEdited = categoryAccess.fetchByPrimaryKey(categoryKey);

        //The category is the owing side so I assume that as the start of all the thinking
        categoryToBeEdited.addSolution(solutionToBeEdited);

        solutionAccess.saveOrUpdate(solutionToBeEdited);
        categoryAccess.saveOrUpdate(categoryToBeEdited);
    }
```

In Category the relevant method is

```
public void addSolution(Solution solutionAdded) {
        //TODO make checks that the solution doesn't already exist. List allows duplicate entries
        if (solutions == null) {
            solutions = new ArrayList<Solution>(1);
        }
        this.solutions.add(solutionAdded);

        if(!solutionAdded.getCategories().contains(this)) {
            solutionAdded.addCategory(this);
        }
    }
```

and in Solution this

```
protected void addCategory(Category categoryAdded) {
        //TODO Check for duplicate blah blah blah
        if (categories == null) {
            categories = new ArrayList<Category>(1);
        }
        this.categories.add(categoryAdded);

        //This is not needed if i make this protected and always work from the category side
        if(!categoryAdded.getSolutions().contains(this)) {
            categoryAdded.addSolution(this);
        }

    }
```

The save or update basically calls entityManagerProvider.get().persist(object) somewhere down the levels (my Access level (DAO)).

So if I run the servlet and this path follows I can see in my SOLUTION_CATEGORY_MAPPING table an entry |solution|category|.

However, if in the same page then I try to fetch the category or solution entry, the list member in the object is null. Shouldn't it bring back something? Or since it's lazy fetch I have to do something to make hibernate retrieve the actual data from the table?

Any help, pointers, suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Where is the code that gets the category and tests if the list is null? Also, calling persist() is wrong: persist() is used to make a transient entity persistent. What you ahve there is al already persistent entity. If your code is inside a transaction (and it should be), you don't need to call any method to persist the changes.

Comment: The addSolution and addCategory are part of the domain classes. The part where I check for null, those are the lists define on the top with the ManyToMany anottation. I have the Transactional in a higher level, in the servlet level. Should I have it in the Service level? Also the code is stripped a bit to make it more readable in the relevant poitns

Comment: So, if you're inside a transaction, the two calls to `saveOrUpdate()` are useless. How do you "fetch the category or solution entry, [and determine that] the list member in the object is null.". Post the relevant code.

Comment: I debugged it and I was looking at the variables in run time. I didn't actually now that perist() is not needed. It seems I might have some misconceptions about that.
fetchByPrimaryKey leads to the entityManagerProvider.get().find(objectClass, primaryKey); down the line and I get the object/entry from there

Comment: Don't use your debugger to determine if something is null. Hibernate uses proxies, and initializes them lazily. Print the value of `category.getSolutions()`, and see.

Comment: Will do that, also are you sure about the saveOrUpdate not being needed. I remember trying it without those and afterwards the tables were not updated in the database. I have the Transactional in the servlet method and it goes like ServletMethod calling ServiceMethod calling AccessMethod. I don't need to put the Transactional in every method right?

Comment: Are you using Spring? Spring's Transactional annotation can't be applied to a servlet method: the servlet is not a Spring bean. It is typically applied on the service method. To answer your question: yes, I'm sure. If it doesn't do that, then you probably don't handle your transactions correctly.

Comment: I am using Guise but I just tried it and it seems to only half work? One of the tables was update (the owing side, maybe this means something) the other not. Thanks for the advise I will look into it a bit more.

Comment: I think I might have an idea what silliness I did. It seems the saveOrUpdate was using merge and the code there was put so if someone entered new info on the other fields in the page they were updated in the column, which is wrong. We should keep funtionalities to independent actions. Basically I think every time it was overwriting the list with a new object. The code I put there is my own, the previous had newly created objects instead of the fetch I do, so a newlly create object had null in the list. I will test it out and see

Comment: Do you have a correct equasl hashcode implementation, because otherwise your contains may do not what you expect. (Keep in mind that you should not use just the id for this check)

Comment: I am not sure what you mean about hashcode implementation.